# Filtering by query string and request path in GraphQL via CloudFlare API

Tags: graphql, postman, cloudflare, cloudflare-api

Is it possible to filter the data by *path* and *query string* in the GraphQL for Cloudflare request now?

I want to achieve [image: the dashboard result] from the Cloudflare API.

What I came up with looks like below:

```
{
    viewer {
        zones(filter: { zoneTag: "MY_ZONE_ID" }) {
            httpRequestsAdaptiveGroups(
                limit: 10000
                filter: {
                    datetime_geq: "2023-10-16T00:00:00Z"
                    datetime_lt: "2023-10-17T00:00:00Z"
                    clientRequestHTTPHost: "my.domain.com"
                }
            ) {
                sum {
                    visits
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've used the schema given in https://pages.johnspurlock.com/graphql-schema-docs/cloudflare.txt, which says

```
clientRequestPath: "/my.file"
clientRequestQuery_like: "?my=query"
```

can be used, but the result is 0 when the above mentioned filters are used. The result is more than 0 when I remove the filters.

The files are accessed for sure, since I can see it from the CF Dashboard.

So I wonder, if filtering with query strings and path is really possible in GraphQL API?

P.S. Cloudflare Network Analysis API is deprecated, so can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

`clientRequestQuery_like` is fussy search with `%` as wildcard,

and `clientRequestQuery` represents the entire query string without the `?` delimiter (ex. `section=539061&expand=comments`)

So you can use like the following query

- `clientRequestQuery_like: "%my=query%"` (include)
- `clientRequestQuery: "my=query"` (exact match)

If you would like to get the same result and query being issued on Cloudflare Dashboard, you can see `graphql` request on Chrome Developer Tools and try it!

[image]

Ref

- [Filtering · Cloudflare Analytics docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/analytics/graphql-api/features/filtering/#string-operators)
- [Fields reference · Cloudflare Ruleset Engine docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ruleset-engine/rules-language/fields/)

Comment: I tried that one as well, but I still got 0 as a result though it's different in CF Dashboard

Comment: @aziza-kasenova I've updated my answer. Can you try the same query retrieved from the dashboard?

Comment: yes, I've tried the same one, with all symbols as in the request, still 0 on Postman

Comment: If it's the case, you should file a support ticket, but you have to see it again if it's really the same query.

Comment: yeah, query is the same since this is how I started filtering. Nice idea with the support ticket, thank you